# OpenApi Basic Auth annotation

Tags: basic-authentication, openapi

I've set up OpenApi annotations and want to enable users to send test requests when viewing the api documentation. I'm only using basic auth, require just the username, no password.

I want to set up my annotations so all of this is already set for the user so that they don't need to do any of it themselves. I've created a username and am stuck at the point where I am not sure how to put it into the annotations so that the "Try me" option doesn't keep returning an "Unauthorized" response.

I have set up the following annotation:

```
/**
 * @OA\OpenApi(
 *    security={{"basicAuth": {}}}
 * )
 *
 * @OA\Components(
 *     @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *         securityScheme="basicAuth",
 *         type="http",
 *         scheme="basic",
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

This results in the following, on my documentation: [image]

I want the username to be automatically filled with a value so that the user never has to bother filling it in. I've tried different ways of trying to achieve this. Nothing I've found online really helps with this, and I tried reading through the `zircote/swagger-php' code but couldn't come up with anything, and I was wondering if somewhere here on Stackoverflow might have some sort of idea.

Comment: 1) What documentation tool do you use - Swagger UI, ReDoc, something else? 2) Did you write the OpenAPI definition manually or generated it from code? If the latter, what library/framework do you use (e.g. Springfox, Swashbuckle, etc.)?

Comment: @Helen I've update the question to give a little more detail as to what I have in place at the moment. I generated the definition from code after annotating all my endpoints. I am  using stoplight elements (https://github.com/stoplightio/elements) for this